# AWS RDS SQL Server - Restrict access to VPC and office IP only

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I'm trying to restrict access to my RDS SQL Server instance to my office IP and all resources in my VPC.

This is what I've tried:

```
MSSQL   TCP 1433    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32  Our Office IP
MSSQL   TCP 1433    yyy.yy.y.y/16       Our AWS VPC (IPv4 CIDR)
```

This seems to be working but I have some doubts:

1. I'm not confident this is the correct approach
2. Can the VPC IPv4 CIDR change on it's own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. I'm not confident this is the correct approach

This is one way of doing this. Its not perfect, but better then exposing your RDS to the entire internet. The better way would be to keep your RDS fully private (no public IP), and access is through VPN from your office, ssh tunnel if you need it for only testing and development.

> Can the VPC IPv4 CIDR change on it's own

No it can't.

Comment: ya that's what I wanted to do.. but team is not yet ready for it

Comment: @NigelFds Limiting access to a given IP is good first step. With time, you may be upgrade to VPN.